# "Hiding" WinAPI calls

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'd like to find a way to somehow "hide" the WinAPI calls I'm using in my code, to make reversing somewhat harder. I realize it's no challenge for a skilled reverser, but my application's security relies heavily on threads, so, for example, messing with the IAT to get rid of CreateThread would be quite distatrous, taking into account it's not very hard to do. I'm therefore searching for a way to call these functions in a less obvious manner (or generally, reproduce their functionality with my call); all I could think of is `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtCreateThreadEx");` which hardly helps. Are there some other, more advanced ways to do this, or maybe some resources that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can mess in user-mode all you want, but in the end your API calls get routed through the SSDT, which can be hooked in kernel mode. Also, aren't you being a little paranoid?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Exactly what I'm talking about, I realize it's perfectly possible for skilled people to get around my stuff, but I want to put off the average guys. As for being paranoid: probably yes, but better safe then sorry :P Also it's a good opportunity to learn something about Win32 internals.

Comment: My suggestion: if you really feel compelled to do something, optimize for the casual attacker. Your application relies on starting threads for security (which by itself sounds strange to me, but whatever)? Start a separate thread also for the main application functionality, that way blindly blocking/diverting CreateThread breaks everything, not just security.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yup, I had that idea already. I'll implement that and think of making some more changes then.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you to write thin wrappers around your Win32 calls. The wrappers should not be static,  they should be generated on the program startup.

You write a set of stubs like `NtCreateThreadEx` that consists of only a ret instruction. After that you link your application with these stubs.

At the startup you generate code that should look pretty much like the code that you presented in your question. You allocate a heap page, place your generated code there, set the execution bit and start it. This code should patch your stubs with real addresses.

There is no single fixed recipe here. You can detour stubs either directly to NT, or to your wrappers that will jump to NT or something similar.

The main point is that once a dynamically generated code is involved, it is way more difficult to understand that code in the plain sight is not the code that will really be used, who and when will generate this code, how this generated code will eventually look like, etc. You can also make the code generation itself tricky.